# Limit lines of contenteditable div with taggle.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, tags

I'm trying to create div, that looks like multiline input and is able to insert tags using taggle.js library. Now I'm struggle with limiting max lines of tags (not characters).

```
<div id="divinput" tabIndex="1" class="custom mcustom textarea" contentEditable>
</div>
```

Very simple demo looks like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/t9sabcy3/1/

Forgive me for putting taggle.css into css section below my scripts (I separated them with long /* ------------------- */ comment), can't append to head this file.
I prepared demo to stop after fullfiling first line.

Problem shows in 3 cases.

First one is simply writing all the time and accepting tags -> although it should stop at first line, the next line shows up.

2nd and 3rd case are connected, if the last tag is very long (in 2nd case less than width of #divinput, in 3rd larger), tag appears in the 2nd line (and in the 3rd case even the 3rd line shows up).

I'm unable to use input (because tags are not working there) and I've tried some options, like preventDefault (as in the demo), setting to nowrap(doesn't work), triggering backspace keydown event (keydown doesn't catch that at all) and now I'm running out of ideas. 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: How about limiting the amount of tags that can be entered: https://github.com/okcoker/taggle.js/issues/39 ?

Comment: It's not a good idea. Tags can be very large (like 100 times letter "a") and it will give amount of tags lines. But thanks for reply.

Comment: Check https://sean.is/poppin/tags/ there is a hook `onBeforeTagAdd` which you might be able to use to see whether the tag will change the container dimensions

Comment: Don't know how to detect height in onBeforeTagAdd, but I'm able to do that in onTagAdd and remove last tag if height is higher, so it resolves 2nd and 3rd case. Thank you! But there still remains first problem.

Comment: @Snaz sounds like you need to temp add the tag, check the height, and then decide if you'll add it or not.

Comment: Yeah, Chris Satchell's idea does this and solves problem with too long tags. The only bug now is when you write all the tags in line (I mean, you have 3 lines and you write 3 lines of tags) and then you try to write anything (doesn't matter if accept), although it shouldn't, it goes to the next (in this example 4th line). I want to block somehow the max + 1 line to appear. If my explanation is not good, I can make images showing what i mean.